# What to use instead of "testDevices" in AdMob for real ADs?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

I am using **firebase_admob** package of Flutter for displaying ads and it works on non-real ads, they appear on app. Also I updated **adUnitId**s to integrate ads to my real admob account.

But, when I want to display real ads I don't have any idea how to do that.

```
MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
  keywords: <String>['game', 'words'],
  testDevices: <String>[],
);

BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  adUnitId: "[here is my unit ID]",
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  },
);

void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: "[my admob ID]");
    super.initState();
}
```

So, what should I write on testDevices in order to show ads to real users without need to write every user's device id manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with some experiments. I placed my app on Play Store, it works fine, it displays ads.

Basically, if you want to show real ads rather than test ads let `testDevices` be null, do not fill it.

And do not forget to put your real unit id from AdMob account as

```
adUnitId: "your unit ID",
```

Final code should look like this:

```
...
MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
  keywords: <String>['game', 'words'],
);

BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  adUnitId: "your unit ID",
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  },
);
...
```